# Error Code: 1366. Incorrect integer value: 'Y' for column 'IsActive' at row 1

Tags: mysql

03:19:51    INSERT INTO students VALUES (NULL,'Craig','Franklin','1970-03-15','M','2010-05-30',3.10,'Y',null,3)     0.000 sec

INSERT INTO students
VALUES (NULL,'Craig','Franklin','1970-03-15','M','2010-05-30',3.10,'Y',null,3);

SELECT * FROM students;

INSERT INTO students
VALUES (NULL,'Harriet','Smith','1982-04-15','F','2010-05-30',3.22, 'Y',null,1);

SELECT * FROM students;

INSERT INTO students
VALUES (NULL,'George','David','1984-11-05','M','2010-10-01',0.00, 'Y',null,3);

SELECT * FROM students;

INSERT INTO students
VALUES (NULL,'Ben','Jefferson','1976-09-25','M','2010-02-21',1.80, 'N','Student on temporary leave to pursue other opportunities but plans on returning in 1 year',3);

SELECT * FROM students;

I changed IsActive to a bit(1) but I am still receiving an error in MySQL. I am trying to get IsActive to allow me place either 'Y' or 'Yes', 'N' or 'No'. I am also trying to insert the above: FirstName, LastName,BirthDate, Gender, StartDate, null for students currently enrolled and statement of withdrawal for last student, 1-4 for year enrolled in school. I've tables for courses and advisors without errors an don't know what is causing error in this INSERT statement.

Do I need to change IsActive to VARCHAR(5)? 
this is the error I receive:
03:19:51    INSERT INTO students VALUES (NULL,'Craig','Franklin','1970-03-15','M','2010-05-30',3.10,'Y',null,3) Error Code: 1366. Incorrect integer value: 'Y' for column 'IsActive' at row 1   0.000 sec

I'm not sure how to correct this error.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please post the sql statement that raise the exception described

Comment: What is your Question, Please Describe details

Comment: I changed IsActive to a bit(1) but I am still receiving an error in MySQL. I am trying to get IsActive to allow me place either 'Y' or 'Yes', 'N' or 'No'. I am also trying to insert the above: FirstName, LastName,BirthDate, Gender, StartDate, null for students currently enrolled and statement of withdrawal for last student, 1-4 for year enrolled in school. I've tables for courses and advisors without errors an don't know what is causing error in this INSERT statement.

Answer (score 0):

isActive column expect integer value but you entered string value('Y'). Please try 1, 0, etc.

Comment: I changed IsActive to a bit(1) but I am still receiving an error in MySQL. I am trying to get IsActive to allow me place either 'Y' or 'Yes', 'N' or 'No'. I am also trying to insert the above: FirstName, LastName,BirthDate, Gender, StartDate, null for students currently enrolled and statement of withdrawal for last student, 1-4 for year enrolled in school. I've tables for courses and advisors without errors an don't know what is causing error in this INSERT statement.